# How can I go through JSON and order it from most to least?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I sort through this JSON and then sort it by most money to least money? I'm trying to create a leaderboard but I keep getting weird things in my console. I tried pushing my external JSON to an array so that it's an array of objects, but I'm not sure if that is what I should be doing.

```
[
   {
      user_id:1,
      money:"496",
      state_id:"19",
      state_name:"Iowa",
      state_abbrev:"IA"
   },
   {
      user_id:2,
      money:"500",
      state_id:"none",
      state_name:"none",
      state_abbrev:"none"
   },
   {
      user_id:3,
      money:"500",
      state_id:"none",
      state_name:"none",
      state_abbrev:"none"
   },
   {
      user_id:4,
      money:"500",
      state_id:"none",
      state_name:"none",
      state_abbrev:"none"
   },
   {
      user_id:5,
      money:"478",
      state_id:"none",
      state_name:"none",
      state_abbrev:"none"
   }
]
```

and order it from most money to least money?

I'm trying to do this right now:

```
var array = []

console.log(array);

var sorted = array.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.array.money - b.array.money;
});


console.log(sorted);
getLeaders().done(function(results){
    $.each(results, function(i, leaderStats){

        array.push(leaderStats);

    });
});
```

Comment: You have an array, and you want to sort it.  The sort function accepts two parameters which are array elements.  Then you compare specific properties of those elements in order to sort.  Each array element (a and b) has a .money property, however it doesn’t have a .array property, not really sure where that came from.  That’s likely the problem.

Comment: @James you're correct, I added that to try to debug it, it has a money but that still doesn't work.

Comment: JSON is a string format. I doubt you want to keep it as a string if you're going to sort objects defined within it...

Comment: @Bkes, create a fiddle demonstrating the problem, please.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan what do you suggest?

Comment: You’re pushing new items into the array inside of getLeaders.done.  You have to sort the array afterwards, sorting an empty array beforehand isn’t useful.

Comment: Apologies for the edit and rollback; I misinterpreted what you are trying to do. Is the array you're showing what comes back from `getLeaders()`? It's best if you can provide an MCVE. See [mcve].

Comment: @James should I just move everything below?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your function is the extra `array` variable:

```
var sorted = array.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.money - b.money;
});
```